# MS Teams bot - create conversation in newly created Group returns 405 BadArgument

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create new convesation for just created channel using Nodejs + botframework v4.9.2.

I've

- created new Channel using POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/${teamId}/channels](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/$%7BteamId%7D/channels)
- new tab using POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/${req.teamId}/channels/${req.channelId}/tabs](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/$%7Breq.teamId%7D/channels/$%7Breq.channelId%7D/tabs)
- I can see new channel and tab in Teams UI
- trying to create new conversation via `Conversations.createConversation` from bot sdk, it's basically calling POST https://directline.botframework.com/v3/conversations with passing new channel id and getting 405 BadArgument `This channel does not support this operation`

I'm running bot locally and proxying via ngrok.
Also I can access GET /v3/conversations.

Updated code

Get Team Memebers `GET ${graphUrl}/groups/${teamId}/members`

Create new Channel

```js
const createChannelRequest: IGraphCreateChannelBody = {
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Teams.Core.channel",
    displayName: channelName,
    description: `This channel is for incident id : ${incidentId}`,
    members: membersIds.map(memberId => (
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
            "user@odata.bind": `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('${memberId}')`,
            roles: ["owner"]
        }
    ))
};

return await graphClient.createChannel(teamId, createChannelRequest);
```

createChannel is basically `POST ${graphUrl}/teams/${teamId}/channels`

Create new Tab `POST ${graphUrl}/teams/${req.teamId}/channels/${req.channelId}/tabs` where channelId is createChannelResponse.id

Create new conversation

```js
const client = new BotConnector.ConnectorClient(credentials, {baseUri: serviceUrl});
const {bot} = TurnContext.getConversationReference(activity);
const createConversationResponse = await client.conversations.createConversation({
    bot,
    activity: incidentActivity,
    members: teamMembers.value.map(member => ({
        id: member.id,
        name: member.displayName
    })),
    channelData: {
        channel: {
            id: newIncidentChannelId
        },
        tenant: {
            id: tenantId
        }
    },
    isGroup: true
});
```

where createConversation fails with 405

Comment: Is your bot actually installed into the channel? If not, it won't be able to initiate a conversation

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm able to communicate with it.

Comment: ah, in that case, you don't need to "createConversation", you'd want "SendToConversation", because the conversation exists already.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow sorry I might have explained it not clearly.
I've installed bot to the team. I'm trying to create new group and send there some message. From my understanding I should create new converstaion for newly created group. I can't use sendToConversation since I don't have existing one.

Comment: @user1469253 - We can see that you're using a Direct Line endpoint. That means the connector client for your `Conversations` object must have a Direct Line base URI. Can you give us an actual code sample that shows how you're constructing these objects? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: (Don't post code in comments, though. Edit it into your question, and make sure it's formatted correctly.)

Comment: as soon as a Team (or channel) is created, the "conversation" is _created_ at the same time. As a result, if you bot is added, it's not "creating" the conversation, it's basically "joining" the existing conversation. As such, it's "sendingToExistingConversation" versus "creatingNewOne", so to speak.

Comment: @KyleDelaney added code sample, please check

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow if conversation is created at the same time as channel, how can I get conversation id in order to continue it via sendingToExistingConversation, I can see API method to GET conversation for a Group but not for a Channel.

Comment: @user1469253 - Is Hilton's answer acceptable?

Comment: @user1469253 - Are you still working on this?

Answer (score 0):

[Posting a complete answer, based on the comments above]

There's no need (and it won't work), in the context of **Teams**, to use `createConversation`, because the *conversation* is created the moment the Team/Channel/Group chat itself is created (`createConversation` exists for other Bot Framework scenarios, and is not applicable for Teams). As a result `SendToConversation` is the correct operation to use.

As to *how to use* `SendToConversation`, there are certain important variables you need to have already your side, and the most common time to get these is when your bot is added to the channel/chat/whatever in the first place. You can read more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications#bot-or-user-added-to-a-team), but more generally, this is considered something called "proactive" messaging, in Teams, and it's worth reading up on that topic more. Please see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-proactive-messaging) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) as good starting points.

Comment: thank you for your reply. But I still do not understand how to post message to a new channel. I can get references when my bot is installed into the Team, but not sure how to use them. I've read documentation and other SO answers but still have no idea.
Again I'm creating new Channel via Graph API and want my bot to post there a message.

Comment: @user1469253 - So are you just trying to learn how to send a proactive message? The documents Hilton linked to explain how to do that. If there's something you don't understand, you need to tell us what specifically you need help with. You asked how to do it and he explained how to do it and all you're saying is you still don't know how to do it and that doesn't give us anything to work with. Help us help you.