# Microsoft Bot Framework API Create Conversation in Teams Group Chat

Tags: node.js, rest, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to send proactive messages to a Teams Group Chat with the Microsoft Bot Framework in NodeJS.

Sending proactive messages to a Teams Channel or a single member is working. But I'm struggling to achieve the same for Group Chats.

This is my code:

```
    postMessageToUser: async (text) => {        
        const audience = undefined;

        var convoParams = {
            isGroup: true,
            members: [
                {
                  id: '29:1iOfFpGevlFyx2SH9V0-KC0Xe4tBIZOSDLDK9a2ZMETtQdRUxQQ7qMBzHFC74VFD3__Vw1uJyzQr7QiBM7TXXXX',
                },
                {
                  id: '29:11lf7x9OmbdGw8aJGAuH3i7_PQYyM1hs6BDZpDo7Wac-n4VCCfLau0TNxvHbfy11dx8x2Sm5BX0dBxNSur_XXXX',
                },
                {
                  id: '29:1VSgyY9QkxAhwmtRNhYGxNvtg5HqvQFQP0Yq9wwop05OCJa_rkTRQGV2Rtq_sspay-1eLN3fuXgy0B0m6qcXXXX',
                }
              ],
            tenantId: "e3988cc8-cd1d-4332-b600-6908eedfXXXX",
            activity: MessageFactory.text(text)
        };

        await adapter.createConversationAsync(bot_config.MicrosoftAppId, "msteams", serviceUrlCache, audience, convoParams, async context => {
            console.log("ok we have context..");

            await context.sendActivity(MessageFactory.text(text));
        });
    },
```

But this doesn't seem to work. The API returns the following error:

```
body: '{"error":{"code":"BadSyntax","message":"Incorrect conversation creation parameters"}}',
```

To clarify, this Group Chat already exists. I'm not trying to create a new Group Chat.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Bot Framework can be used for a variety of scenarios, and so not all of it's capabilities work in all settings. In this case, inside Teams, you can't 'create' a conversation because it exists already, so you need instead to `SendToConversation`. See here for a more detailed answer: [MS Teams bot - create conversation in newly created Group returns 405 BadArgument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62917064/ms-teams-bot-create-conversation-in-newly-created-group-returns-405-badargumen/62930478#62930478)